# Azure Docker Django sqlite3 not deploying

Tags: django, azure, docker

I have spent an entire day trying to deploy a simple Django app to Azure with a docker container following this [links](https://medium.com/zeitcode/a-simple-recipe-for-django-development-in-docker-bonus-testing-with-selenium-6a038ec19ba5) advice.

Dockerfile:

```
# My Site
# Version: 1.0
FROM python:3.7.2
# Install Python and Package Libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    net-tools \
    vim
# Project Files and Settings
RUN mkdir -p myproject
WORKDIR /myproject
COPY requirements.txt manage.py . ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Server
EXPOSE 8000
STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  django:
    container_name: django_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: johnmweisz/education_app:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/myproject
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

using docker-compose build/run locally works perfectly fine but when deploying the app from https://cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/johnmweisz/education_app
to Azure it will not start and says that it cannot find manage.py.

I keep going in circles trying to find instructions that work.  Anyone with advice please help.

Comment: Even if you could get this working, it is not the right way to go. `runserver` is **not** for production use. Use a proper wsgi server.

Comment: Which service in Azure do you use? The Azure Web App for Container? And do you use the image or the docker-compose file to deploy?